# Vue3 Web Components events not working with custom wrapper

Tags: javascript, dom-events, vuejs3, web-component

The WebComponents do work fine with this custom script but I have problems to.
I want to be able to add event listener from outside to listen to the custom Vue events fired from within the component (in this example on click on the WC). Thus I created an event proxy but for some reason the listener is never triggered. Obviously I made a mistake somewhere. So I hope that someone can point me to the right solution.

I made a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-http-b38se) for you to take a look and play around with the code.

(as CodeSandbox has some issues you'll need to click on the reload button on the right side of the layout in order to make it work)

```
//main.js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import WebComponentService from "./services/wc";
WebComponentService.init();

createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

Vue Component used as source file for Web Component

```
//src/wcs/MyComp.vue
<template>
  <div class="m" @click="click">
    Hello My Comp {{ name }}
    <div v-for="(i, index) in values" :key="index">ID: {{ i.title }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  __useShadowDom: false,
  emits: ["my-click"],
  // emits: ["my-click", "myclick"],
  props: {
    name: {
      default: "Test",
    },
    values: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {
        return [{ title: "A" }, { title: "B" }];
      },
    },
  },
  methods: {
    click() {
      // emit the event
      this.$emit("my-click");
      console.log("EMIT");
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="less" scoped>
.m {
  border: 5px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>
```

Index.html where I test the web component and added an event listener

```
<!-- public/index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico" />
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
    <h3>WC Test here</h3>

    <div class="component-canvas">
      <!-- web component testing -->
      <xvue-my-comp
        id="vtest"
        name="MyComp HTML Rendering"
        :values='[{"title": "Element 1"}, {"title": "Element"}]'
        >Inner HTML Caption</xvue-my-comp
      >
    </div>

    <script>
      const mySelector = document.querySelector("xvue-my-comp");
      //listen to the event
      mySelector.addEventListener("my-click", function (ev) {
        console.log("@LISTEN");
        alert(ev);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Custom WebComponents wrapper

```
import HTMLParsedElement from "html-parsed-element";
import { createApp, h, toHandlerKey } from "vue";
import { snakeCase, camelCase } from "lodash";

let registeredComponents = {};

const tagPrefix = "xvue-"; // Prefix for Custom Elements (HTML5)
const vueTagPrefix = "xvue-init-"; // Prefix for VUE Components - Must not be tagPrefix to avoid loops

// We use only one file as web component for simplicity
// and because codesandbox doesen't work with dynamic requires
const fileName = "MyComp.vue";
const webComponent = require(`../wcs/MyComp.vue`);

const componentName = snakeCase(
  camelCase(
    // Gets the file name regardless of folder depth
    fileName
      .split("/")
      .pop()
      .replace(/.ce/, "")
      .replace(/\.\w+$/, "")
  )
).replace(/_/, "-");
// store our component
registeredComponents[componentName] = {
  component: webComponent.default
};

export default {
  init() {
    // HTMLParsedElement is a Polyfil Library (NPM Package) to give a clean parsedCallback as the browser
    // default implementation has no defined callback when all props and innerHTML is available
    class VueCustomElement extends HTMLParsedElement {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      constructor() {
        super();
      }

      parsedCallback() {
        console.log("Legacy Component Init", this);

        if (!this.getAttribute("_innerHTML")) {
          this.setAttribute("data-initialized", this.innerHTML);
        }

        let rootNode = this;
        let vueTagName = this.tagName
          .toLowerCase()
          .replace(tagPrefix, vueTagPrefix);
        let compBaseName = this.tagName.toLowerCase().replace(tagPrefix, "");
        let compConfig = registeredComponents[compBaseName];

        // Optional: Shadow DOM Mode. Can be used by settings __useShadowDom in component vue file
        if (compConfig.component.__useShadowDom) {
          rootNode = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
          document
            .querySelectorAll('head link[rel=stylesheet][href*="core."]')
            .forEach((el) => {
              rootNode.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
            });
        }

        if (vueTagName) {
          // If we have no type we do nothing
          let appNode = document.createElement("div");
          // let appNode = rootNode;
          appNode.innerHTML +=
            "<" +
            vueTagName +
            ">" +
            this.getAttribute("data-initialized") +
            "</" +
            vueTagName +
            ">"; // @TODO: Some issues with multiple objects being created via innerHTML and slots
          rootNode.appendChild(appNode);

          // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-this-alias
          const self = this;

          function createCustomEvent(name, args) {
            return new CustomEvent(name, {
              bubbles: false,
              cancelable: false,
              detail: args.length === 1 ? args[0] : args
            });
          }

          const createEventProxies = (eventNames) => {
            const eventProxies = {};
            if (eventNames) {
              console.log("eventNames", eventNames);
              // const handlerName = toHandlerKey(camelCase(name));
              eventNames.forEach((name) => {
                const handlerName = name;
                eventProxies[handlerName] = (...args) => {
                  this.dispatchEvent(createCustomEvent(name, args));
                };
              });
            }
            return eventProxies;
          };
          const eventProxies = createEventProxies(compConfig.component.emits);
          this._props = {};

          const app = createApp({
            render() {
              let props = Object.assign({}, self._props, eventProxies);
              // save our attributes as props
              [...self.attributes].forEach((attr) => {
                let newAttr = {};
                newAttr[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
                props = Object.assign({}, props, newAttr);
              });
              console.log("props", props);
              delete props.dataVApp;
              return h(compConfig.component, props);
            },

            beforeCreate: function () {}
          });

          // Append only relevant VUE components for this tag
          app.component(vueTagPrefix + compBaseName, compConfig.component);

          this.vueObject = app.mount(appNode);
          console.log("appNode", app.config);
        }
      }

      disconnectedCallback() {
        if (this.vueObject) {
          this.vueObject.$destroy(); // Remove VUE Object
        }
      }

      adoptedCallback() {
        //console.log('Custom square element moved to new page.');
      }
    }

    // Register for all available component tags ---------------------------

    // Helper to Copy Classes as customElement.define requires separate Constructors
    function cloneClass(parent) {
      return class extends parent {};
    }

    for (const [name, component] of Object.entries(registeredComponents)) {
      customElements.define(tagPrefix + name, cloneClass(VueCustomElement));
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I put a ``console.log("Hello World")`` before your ``this.dispatchEvent``.. and it was never executed..

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thanks and yes there might be multiple issues. Still the main one is that even manually triggered events aren't listenable from outside.

Answer (score 2):

If I whack this into your `render` method, it all works fine.

Thus your problem is not Web Components or Events related

```
              document.addEventListener("foo", (evt) => {
                console.log("FOOd", evt.detail, evt.composedPath());
              });
              self.dispatchEvent(
                new CustomEvent("foo", {
                  bubbles: true,
                  composed: true,
                  cancelable: false,
                  detail: self
                })
              );
```

#### addendum after comment:

- Your code has `bubbles:false` - that will never work
- This code properly emits an Event
- You need to look into **how** you trigger **your** proxy code

```
          const createCustomEvent = (name, args = []) => {
            return new CustomEvent(name, {
              bubbles: true,
              composed: true,
              cancelable: false,
              detail: !args.length ? self : args.length === 1 ? args[0] : args
            });
          };

          const createEventProxies = (eventNames) => {
            const eventProxies = {};
            if (eventNames) {
              eventNames.forEach((name) => {
                const handlerName =
                  "on" + name[0].toUpperCase() + name.substr(1).toLowerCase();
                eventProxies[handlerName] = (...args) => {
                  appNode.dispatchEvent(createCustomEvent(name));
                };
              });
              document.addEventListener("foo",evt=>console.warn("foo!",evt));
              appNode.dispatchEvent(createCustomEvent("foo"));
              console.log(
                "@eventProxies",
                eventProxies,
                self,
                "appnode:",
                appNode,
                "rootNode",
                rootNode
              );
            }
            return eventProxies;
          };
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint Danny! This is correct but the strange thing is that  self.dispatchEvent() doesen't work when placed inside createEventProxies method only document.dispatchEvent() works there.

Comment: see addendum, ``self``, ``rootNode``, ``appNode`` all work as dispatch location; **but you do need ``bubbles:true``**

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try to use Vue3's (since 3.2) `defineCustomElement`

```
import CustomElement from './some/path/CustomElement.ce.vue'

const CustomElementCE = defineCustomElement(CustomElement)
customElements.define('custom-element', CustomElementCE);
```

More on that here: [Vue web components](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/web-components.html#definecustomelement)

Comment: Thanks but it has to be the custom wrapper. Vue3 defineCustomElement works only with shadow dom while I need it to also be able to produce proper html for what I have in my mind.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I'm definitely interested in this post as I'm struggling with pretty much the same thing. Please, if you find an answer, let us know.

Comment: I posted a solution in case you're still interested.

Comment: Nice, thanks! I've used some of your ideas and added some of my own. Even though 
my use-case might be a bit different, feel free to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70673060/14412426

Answer (score 0):

I found one possible solution. As stated in the vue docs we can use static event listeners that are passed as props. They have to be prefixed with "on" i.E. `onMyevent` for event name `my-event`. Though it works fine - the downside is that I can't pass any arguments as I don't see where to get them from.

One strange thing is that I cant add this event to the instance. Something like `self.dispatchEvent()` doesn't work when placed inside `createEventProxies` method. So I have to stick to `document.dispatchEvent()`

Working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-keller-md9vf-test-a-md9vf?file=/src/services/wc.js).

```
  const createCustomEvent = (name, args = []) => {
    return new CustomEvent(name, {
      bubbles: false,
      composed: true,
      cancelable: false,
      detail: !args.length ? self : args.length === 1 ? args[0] : args
    });
  };

  const createEventProxies = (eventNames) => {
    const eventProxies = {};
    if (eventNames) {
      eventNames.forEach((name) => {
        const handlerName =
          "on" + name[0].toUpperCase() + name.substr(1).toLowerCase();
        eventProxies[handlerName] = (...args) => {
          document.dispatchEvent(createCustomEvent(name));
        };
      });
      console.log("@eventProxies", eventProxies);
    }
    return eventProxies;
  };
```